# Flutter formKey currentstate is null when pass to another widget

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, flutter-form-builder

I'm trying to create a Textbutton widget with a `disabled` property like this:

```
class AppTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final void Function(BuildContext context) onPress;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry margin;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final double borderRadius;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Image? leadingIcon;
  final Image? trailingIcon;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final bool disabled;

  AppTextButton(this.title, this.onPress,
      {this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
      this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      this.borderRadius = 0,
      this.leadingIcon,
      this.trailingIcon,
      this.textStyle,
      this.disabled = false,
      this.backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFFFFFFF)});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: margin,
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius))),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(backgroundColor)),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            if (this.leadingIcon != null) ...[this.leadingIcon!],
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: padding,
                child:
                    Text(title, textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: textStyle),
              ),
            ),
            if (this.trailingIcon != null) ...[this.trailingIcon!]
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () => !disabled ? onPress(context) : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in my screen, I declare my formKey and my form as following:

```
class LoginScreen extends AppBaseScreen {
  LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Obx(
                    () => AppTextInput(
                      "Please input passcode",
                      _passwordController,
                      borderRadius: 8,
                      fillColor: Color(0xFFF6F4F5),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      errorMessage: _c.errorLoginConfirm.value,
                      isObscure: true,
                      onChange: _onInputChange,
                      maxLength: 6,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 20, right: 20),
                      validator: (text) {
                        if (text != null && text.length > 0) {
                          if (text.length < 6) {
                            return "Passcode must have at least 6 digits";
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )),
```

And I will have a button at the bottom of the screen, which I pass the `!_formKey.currentState!.validate()` in the disabled field

```
AppTextButton("Login", _onLogin,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 24, 24, 8),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFF353C),
                  disabled: !_formKey.currentState!.validate(),
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: 8),
```

However, the formKey.currentState is null and throw the following error everytime the screen is opened.
`Null check operator used on a null value`

What I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a stateful widget? Since your UI needs to be updated depending on form validation state, it is not a stateless widget.

Comment: Hi @PeterKoltai I use separate controller and binding from `https://pub.dev/packages/get`

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the form state before passing,

```
final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
formState.save();


onPressed: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                final FormState formState = _formKey.currentState;
                if (formState.validate()) {
                  formState.save();
                  onPress(context);
                }
              },
```

Comment: Hi Sachin, where should I put the above two lines? Currently, I put them inside build function. However, when I tried to print the `_formKey.currentState`, the result is null.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should know how the widgets building process (Assume you have `Botton` widget and `Input` widget):

1. `Botton` and `Input` are building initial state. both states are not yet ready to be read and used
2. `Botton` and `Input` are built. States are ready to read.
3. User interact to `Input`. `Input` must call `Button` to rebuild its state if the value passes the validator
4. `Botton` rebuild.

For the process, you should change your code like:

1. Get and modify the state of `Button` inside `Input`
2. Notify `Button` to rebuild

There are many ways to handle the [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) between widgets. I simply change the AppTextButton into Statefultwidget to achieve it.

```
...
final _buttonKey = GlobalKey<_AppTextButtonState>();
...
  AppTextButton(key: _buttonKey)
...


class AppTextButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool initDisable;

  AppTextButton({
    this.initDisable = false,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppTextButtonState createState() => _AppTextButtonState();
}

class _AppTextButtonState extends State<AppTextButton> {
  var disable;

  @override
  void initState() {
    disable = widget.initDisable;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(child: Text('Button'), onPressed: disable ? null : () {});
  }

  void enableButton() {
    setState(() {
      disable = false;
    });
  }

  void disableButton() {
    setState(() {
      disable = true;
    });
  }
}


class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validator: (text) {
          if (text != null && text.length > 0) {
            if (text.length < 6) {
              return "Passcode must have at least 6 digits";
            }
          }
        },
        onChanged: (v) {
          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
            _buttonKey.currentState?.enableButton();
          } else {
            _buttonKey.currentState?.disableButton();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused because all the widgets are created at the same time, so the `_formKey.currentState` is still null when the `AppTextButton` calls it.

You need to create a separate controller to control the state of the button and add it to the validator like this:

```dart
validator: (text) {

                     if (text != null && text.length > 0) {
                        if (text.length < 6) {
                           buttonDisableController = true;
                           return "Passcode must have at least 6 digits";
                        }
                     }
                     buttonDisableController = false;
                     return null;
                  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need this anymore but for those who came across and needs a way to handle:

Form state is null on page build. Hence you can't give it directly. You need to use `onChange` callback of text input widget.

```
bool disabled = true;
...
onChange: (text) => setState(() => disabled = !_formKey.currentState!.validate())
...
disabled: disabled,
```

and give `disabled` value to AppTextButton

note: this will do auto validation on each change in inputs and will show validation messages

note: you can handle state management in the way you wish